# Cannot install some apps on Galaxy Note 10.1: parse error

Tags: applications, installation

I downloaded Awesome note Hd and Awesome note-jujuburi. But I can't install both of them on my *Galaxy Note 10.1:* my device showed "parse error".

I activated *Unknown sources*, and cleared data/cache in Google Play, but this error note remains.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just for clarification: Are you trying to install from Google Play, or from other sources? The *unknown sources* option is not needed for Google Play, it's rather a security measure to prevent installation from other sources.

Comment: Here's an old SO question that seems similar in nature. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492401/parse-error-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package-while-installing-android Does it help at all?

Answer (score 0):

"Parse error" often means a particular application will not run, and therefore, cannot be installed on a particular device. This restriction is often set in apps using the `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` tags respectively. If the Android firmware version installed on your device does not fall within the supported versions defined by the tags, then you will get the "parse error" message during installation.

Or, the Android package file (APK) is corrupted so the Application Manager cannot verify the checksum in order to proceed with the installation.